# CorePlot 1.5.1 fails to install with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, core-plot

I am new to CocoaPods. I have followed the instructions from the very good tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 and installing AFNetworking (the pod given in the tutorial) works without any problem. However, when I tried to install CorePlot with CocoaPods, I got the error message:

> Downloading dependencies
>
> Installing CorePlot (1.5.1)
>
> [!] /bin/bash
>
> set -e
>
> dtrace -h -s framework/TestResources/CorePlotProbes.d -o
>
> framework/Source/CorePlotProbes.h
>
> sh: line 2: dtrace: command not found

And when I try with older versions of CorePlot, it does not work either. Any idea?

Thank you!

PS: BTW, my Podfile is

`# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.1'

target 'test' do
pod 'CorePlot'
end

target 'testTests' do

end`

Comment: Please post your podfile (at least the parts relevant to Core Plot).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following podfile with Xcode 6.1.1 and CocoaPods 0.35.0 and it worked fine:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, "8.0"

target "test" do
    pod 'CorePlot'
end

target "testTests" do

end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have copy and pasted your podfile, and executed it with Xcode 6.1.1 and CocoaPods 0.35.0 and I obtain the exact same error message. Would it be possible that the compiler is stuck with the last line of the 'CorePlot.podspec', i.e. "dtrace -h -s framework/TestResources/CorePlotProbes.d -o framework/Source/CorePlotProbes.h"? I have tried yesterday to see whether DTRACE was well installed in my shell. It runs 'isnoop' DTRACE command without any problem but does not recognize the command 'dtrace'. I don't know if it is linked, but it might give you a hint about the issue

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root of the problem: for some reason, my ~/.bash_profile was missing one or more of the paths listed here:

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

That's why some functions, such as 'dtrace' for instance, were missing.